# Dynamic image file generated by ASP.NET generic handler(.ashx) not working with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've downloaded a JQuery plugin (fancyzoom.js) that can zoom-in an image upon clicking by a user.

The HTML tag looks like this:

```
<img class="fancyzoom" src="images/myproduct.jpg" width="100px" alt='' />
```

and the JS:

```
$(function () {
  $('img.fancyzoom').fancyzoom();
});
```

This works correctly. I can zoom the image, but when I change the image tag into this using a generic handler:

```
<img class="fancyzoom" width="100px" src="ProductImage.ashx?productId=myproduct" alt=''/>
```

,the image was loaded fine initially but clicking it that is suppose to be zoomed in  doesn't work. No errors detected.
Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've failed to figure out a way on how **fancyzoom** can be configured to accept streamed images, so I ended using **fancybox** instead. Using this works alright:

```
$(function () {
  $('img.fancybox').fancybox({'type':'image'});
});
```